# Ajax with jquery callback to php file on Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have the following situation trying to use Ajax in Wordpress.

**1.** The file to be called has only a tiny code like: `<?php echo "Whatever" ?>`

**2.** it is to be called to and by button `onclick`:

```
<button id="ajaxbtn" onclick="showPopup()" class="btn-shape"></button>

<div id="ajax-input"></div>
```

**3.** Functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data', 99 );

function myajax_data() {
   wp_localize_script('ajax-wear', 'myajax',
   array(
      'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
    )
  );
}
```

---

```
add_action('wp_ajax_tablo', 'tablo');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_tablo', 'tablo');

function tablo() {
    ob_start();

    get_template_part(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'extra-wear' );
    $result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $return = array('content' => $result);

    wp_send_json($return);

    wp_die();
}
```

**4.** Jquery

```
jQuery("#ajaxbtn").click(function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: myajax.ajax_url,
    data: {
      action: 'tablo'
    },
    success: function(response) {
      jQuery('#ajax-input').html(response.content);
    }
  });
});
```

**5.** Present output.
In the console there is information that XHR finished loading: Post "http//....." but nothing is really posted.

Has someone any idea what could be wrong with that code? my quess is point. 3
Any good advise highly appreciated.

Comment: Nothing is posted or nothing is returned? Is there an error in the dev tools network tab? any console error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When posting snippets of code, you do not have to use single backticks for every line, you can wrap blocks of code using three backticks at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: it is posted as in the console there is the message  XHR finished loading: Post .. , in the network there is an admin-ajax status. 200 and no error anywhere, but nothing returned

Answer (score 0):

For what I see, you have two problems:

1. the dataType: 'json' parameter, most probably because you're not sending data in a json format
2. the "response.content" should be just "response"

Also, no idea if the URL you pass in "myajax.ajax_url" has been declared before this bit of code?

One more thing, "success" is depreciated since jQuery 1.8, and you should now use done() instead.

With all of that considered, how about trying this and see if it works?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'path/to/your-ajax-file.php',
    data: { action: 'tablo' }
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $('#ajax-input').html(response);
});
```

I added a console.log(response); line in the function so you can also see the result in your JavaScript console, remove it once your script works!

Answer (score 0):

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` is apparently  not a correct way to build a path to call a file in that function. Once amended the content returned.